# Roots of a degree N polynomial for large N

Tags: functional-analysis, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

### The question

For a large natural number $N$ I want to know all the roots $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,...,\lambda_N$  of
$$ p(\lambda) \; = \; \lambda^N -a \,  \lambda^{N-1} - 1 \; , $$
where $a$ is a non-zero real number which can be restricted to $a>1$.

#### Context

This question appears as the eigenvalues of the $N \times N$ matrix
$$
T(a) \; = \; \begin{bmatrix} a & &  & &   1 \\ 1 & 0 &  & & 
 \\  & 1 &0 & &     \\  &  & \ddots & \ddots &    \\  &  & & 1 &0 \end{bmatrix}_{N\times N} \; \quad [\text{ entries not shown are  zero}] .
$$
The matrix $T(0)$ is the translation matrix in a lattice of $N$ sites with periodic boundary conditions, i.e. $T(0)$ sends the basis vectors $e_{N}\to e_{1}$ and $e_n\to e_{n+1}$ for $n=1,...,N-1$. The eigenvalues of $T(0)$ are the $N$-th roots of unit.

In my problem, the translation invariance is broken and appears the $a \neq 0$ term.

---

#### My thoughts on this problem

A general solution for every $N$ must be possible but very cumbersome (probably involving some hypergeometric functions). A similar equation was solved exactly in this paper [math/9411224v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9411224v1) by M.L.Glasser. He found the roots of $x^N - x + t= 0$, which is equivalent to the problem $y^N - a y^{N-1} + a = 0$, for $y=1/x$ and $a=1/t$, which is almost the problem that I am interested.

The large $N$ limit seen to be easier to study the reciprocal problem for $x= 1/\lambda$ in which the equation is $1 - a\, x-x^{N}=0$. For $N$ *even*  the roots $\{ x_i \}$, which are such that $x^{N}+a x -1 = (x-x_1)...(x-x_N)$, satisfies
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2} + ... \frac{1}{x_N} &= a \; . \qquad (*)
\end{align}
By definition, a root must satisfy $x^{N}_{i} = 1 + \eta \, x_{i}$ which sujest me to take the $N$-th root and get
$$ x_{i} \; = \; \zeta_{i} \;  \left( 1 + \eta \, x_{i} \right)^{1/N} \; = \;  \zeta_{i} \;  \exp \left[ \frac{1}{N}\log\left( 1 + \eta \, x_{i} \right) \right] \; , $$
where $\zeta_{i}$ is one of the $N$-th roots of unity. Taking the limit $N \to \infty$ *seems* that the roots $x_i$ tends to the roots of unity, but this must be false since the equation $(*)$ will no longer be satisfied [the sum does not even converge absolutely fo $x_i=\zeta_i$].

---

### Edit:

As Robert Israel pointed, my problem can be related to the roots of
$$ x^{N} - x + z \; = \; 0 \; , $$
which, according to the Glasser's solution, are
$$ x_{i} \; = \; \omega_{i}^{-1} \; - \; 
\frac{z}{N-1} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\; \frac{ \Gamma \left( \frac{Nn}{N-1}+1 \right) }{ \Gamma \left( n+2 \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{n}{N-1}+1 \right) } \; z^{n} \, \omega_{i}^{n} \; , \text{for } i=1,...,N-1\; ,$$
where $\omega_i$ are the $N-1$-th roots of identity, and $x_N=-x_1-...-x_{N-1}$.

#### Question: what is the limit $N\to \infty$?

**comment 1:** I am trying to convert to a Riemann sum ($\Delta n = \frac{1}{N-1}$) but I am having trouble manipulation the $N-1$ terms inside the gamma function.

**comment 2:**  In Wikipedia, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Example), cites these roots as an application of *Lagrange inversion theorem*, but I can't show that this solution is equal to Glasser's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is equivalent to Glasser's with $\lambda =  (-a)^{1/(1-N)}/z$ and
$t = - (-a)^{N/(1-N)}$.